# Is it possible to use "document.all" in IE11 without changing every usage?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am working on old project. In which `document.all()` is used in JavaScript. The same command working fine in IE8, 9, 10 but does not work on IE11.

I came to know that we need to use `document.getElementById()`, but I need to change nearly 1000 JSP files for this change.

Please suggest - *is there any alternative to make it possible*?

Comment: The problem with shimming *document.all* is that it's actually a property that can be called, e.g. `document.all('foo')` is the same as `document.all['foo']` and also it treats name and ID properties the same ('foo' can be a name or ID).

Comment: @user2864740—yes, as long as the use is restricted to what *getElementById* does, but then global replacement would work too. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It *is* possible to use `document.all(id)` and `document.all[id]` in IE11/Edge - at least when site has an HTML4 doctype, and perhaps related compatibility features. It also appears to work (for me) in E11/Edge & HTML5; YMMV on this last configuration.

That is, even though it is ["no longer supported"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - *and* is [even marked as removed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx) (so YMMV outside of 'compatibility' modes) -  it *is still implemented* in IE11. Windows XP is "no longer supported" but it continues to be used and still runs as well as it ever did .. never mind it being an abandoned ship. (The documentation alludes to only the HTML5 doctype triggering the green field behavior; although I cannot observe the claimed effects.)

Since this is an "old project" the easiest solution would be leave it alone, triggering an IE 'compatibility mode' as required; there are likely many other antiquated approaches anyway. That is, leave the site as HTML4 as this is, after all, an "old project".

While I initially suggested 'shimming'<sup>1</sup> in a comment the property/object required is problematic for several reasons and the `all[id]` form cannot be emulated as RobG pointed out. Also, such a shim wouldn't actually update the code to use the approved methods - it'd just be a lie and run counter to the reason why such was removed to begin with.

Thus, if desiring *change the deprecated/obsolute usage* the proper solution *is* to modify the "1000 JSP files". With a little bit of analysis this ought to be possible with a mostly-automated global replacement followed by a diff/delta code-review.

---

<sup>1</sup>FWIW, the most basic shim, assuming that reassignment to document.all is possible in IE11-where-document.all-is-really-removed, would be something like:

```
if (!document.all) {
   document.all = document.getElementById;
}
```

This would allow `document.all(someId)` but *not* `all(name)`, `all[id]`, `all.length`, or `all.item(id)`. The current usage of `document.all` would still need to looked at to make sure the shim covered existing usages; and the few usages that are not covered should be updated wholesale.

If such a shim was sufficient it would still need to be injected into all the "1000 JSP files"; hopefully there is already a common script file ..

Comment: maybe it's only enabled in compatibility mode? i can't try at the moment

Comment: @Worf Yeah; I'm a bit unsure about it. In IE11/Edge/HTML4 `document.all` *is* present though. It might be HTML5 (non-compatiblity, but still IE11/Edge) that is the trigger for this.

Comment: @Worf I can't actually get `document.all` to go away. I'd like to see an example where it truly is "removed" as the documentation claims..

Comment: @Worf It was working fine when we use compatibility mode. But customer is not agreeing to use compatibility mode..

Comment: @phanikrishna What HTML doctype is used? Do you have a minimal HTML file that shows document.all "not working"? I don't believe `document.all` is removed under HTML4 (the documentation indicates the HTML5 doctype is a required trigger); but I cannot trigger document.all to go away, even under E11/Edge & HTML5. This doesn't mean there isn't some wonky local setting/configuration on my system, however .. but I *do not* explicitly choose a compatibility mode and `document.all` remains available.

Answer (score 0):

By forcing IE11 to emulate IE10 (i used meta tags `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"/>`document.all becomes available.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/woqiliweya/1/edit?js,output)